# Super wet reverbed instrument into a vibrato pedal

Tags: sound-effects, reverb, analog, sound-quality, pitch-shifting

I would like to send a long-tailed-reverbed signal (guitar/violin) into an analog vibrato pedal. I'm talking about a 10 seconds decay reverb (or longer), and a vibrato with a rate way under 1 Hz. The goal is to get an ambient vintage LFO style on a long reverb tail generated from a real physical instrument.

Are the classical analog vibrato pedals like the Boss-VB designed to handle this kind of super-wet reverbed audio, or do they only work cleanly when they are fed dry instrument signals ? If so, which other solution should I consider?

Comment: 1st, why wouldn't it, and 2nd it's pretty easy to try it somehow even if the pedal is not the exact same but has similar characteristics (e.g. analog - optical etc..)

Comment: Thank you.
1st) I was thinking the circuit was maybe optimized for specific instrument signals, or that it would somehow sound glitchy or noisy with richer audio in. Of course it will depend on the hardware I'll be using, but some user experience is always welcome
2nd) I don't have any vibrato pedal for now, and I wanted to make sure that it would fit my needs before investing in anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pedal does one thing well. It doesn't care what audio you put into it, it'll do its thing regardless.

As long as the signal is not too loud, you should be fine. Certain frequencies may sound better (hence why they make certain pedals specific to bass guitar), but generally (if it's a decent pedal) the actual tone of the incoming signal should not be affected too much. Also, guitar and violin are generally in the same spectrum of frequencies, so again you should be fine.